# How to organise sending an email from my android app

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have to send an email from `IntentService`. My data is mostly the backup from a phone. I am using `smtp.google.com` + `javamail`.I can use a gmail account and send data through it.(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail):
From my point of view the problem with this approach is that my app uses the gmail account and sends data via my account. All personal data would go through one my account. **Question#1** - Is it a good approach to do it?

The gmail api uses OAuth 2.0. And I have to store my client ID in some place of my program. I read that it is impossible to restore login/password from it. This token has validity. **Question#2** Is it possible to use this token for reading or deleting something from gmail account until it is valid?

For all examples of my app would be the same gmail account. This think bothers me sometimes, because if something happens with gmail account I will not be able to do anything. 
**Question#3** Is it worth to use services like https://www.mailgun.com/ or maybe to create at least another gmail account and to use them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only if you're the only one using your app.
2. Yes.
3. Email is probably not the right solution to your problem.  But without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve and what your requirements are, it's hard to know what to suggest instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  My service is very simple - it makes the backup of contacts of a phone and sends it to dropbox and google drive and to an email of user. I don't know how many users I would have, but this app is not only for me. The question is: Is it possible to use the Gmail service just for sending mails, and not to store it? Or maybe you know other mail service which can do it?

Comment: I just noticed that you are the primary developer of the JavaMail API.  It is a really great project, I am enjoy using it )

Comment: If you assume that all the users of your app have a Gmail account, and you want to use their own Gmail account to send the message, then you're going to need to ask the user for their username and password, or use [OAuth2 authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) to get a token to access their account.